# Can Django-CMS custom plugins be restricted to a specific template?

Tags: django-cms

I have a very simple plugin in my cms_plugins.py file

I want the editors of the site, to only be able to select this plugin form a specific template.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes have a look at the CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF setting

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have a lot of amazing choices in Django CMS please listen to the amazing tutorial with source code and video tutorial in Django-CMS here in this link [**here**](https://github.com/mkoistinen/staff-app-demo)
it is illustrate **Django CMS Plugin** step by step and placeholder in django cms